# Efficient MySQL Query: running various queries through multiple tables, assigning result tables to array

Tags: php, mysql, performance

Is there a way of running a single MySQL query, which selects data from various tables and returns each table individually that can be assigned to an array, in PHP, instead of a query for each table and assigning the results manually to the array?

For instance

```
// Interpretation: 
$multiple       = mysql_query("select * from table_a; select * from table_b;");
foreach ($multiple as $table => $results) {
    $tables[$table] = $results;
}
```

instead of:

```
$tables         = array (
    "table_a"   => mysql_query ("select * from table_a;"),
    "table_b"   => mysql_query ("select * from table_b;"),
);
```

Any guidance will be most appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: They're in the same database, however they're both required for data they hold. There are no foreign columns relating the two tables.

Comment: When I said are they related, I meant is there some field which connects the tables, that way you can select all the columns of them based on that relation, and then you can add each column to the specific array. _EDIT_: Okay, since there are no relations, I don't think there is a way to fetch them both at once.

Comment: Why not run individual queries for selecting data from individual tables? If the tables have the same structure, you may perhaps do UNION

Answer (score 1):

Not without nasty SQL tricks. I don't think your suggested way is any more efficient though. If the two tables are huge, it will be better to break the huge request into two not-so-huge requests.

If they are relatively tiny, it still won't make much of a difference.

However, if bandwidth is at a premium, I'm still not sure there's anyway to grab two tables in one query.

Comment: They're relatively small tables, however they will be later expanded with from around 10 rows, to about 100. I was just opting for speed an efficiency and looking for a better way in approaching this task. What are the "nasty" SQL tricks you mentioned?

Comment: I don't have any examples, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use union ?

```
$multiple = mysql_query("select 'table_a', table_a.* from table_a union select 'table_b', table_b.* from table_b");
$tables=array();
foreach ($multiple as $table => $results)
{
    $tables[$results[0]] = array_shift($results);
}
```

If the number of columns in table is different just put NULL instead of missing columns. I will sugest not to use * at all unless in testing.

example query for different number of columns:

```
select 'table_a', table_a.col1, table_a.col2, table_a.col3 from table_a union select 'table_b', table_b.col1, table_b.col2, NULL from table_b;
```

Answer (score 0):

open two DB links, do querys with mysql_unbuffered_query. Mysql_unbuffered_query executes the query but returns inmediately to php code, while mysql engine proccess the query. later, when you use mysql_fetch_row and so, is when the data is REALLY retrieved from mysql engine.

this way, if you do the two querys in two db links (two mysql_connect), each query for each link, you can start to work with the first, and the mysql engine is 'caching/working' in the second while your php code is executing.

Also, if you use unbuffered queries, you can't do mysql_num_rows or so, because can be that the complete resultset is not in memory yet.

mysqli->query("...", MYSQLI_ASYNC) or PDO/MYSQL is a better and modern way to do this, but you need a mysqlnd or a libmysql compatible with ASYNC queries.